# Why does M365 keep accepting phishing emails that Gmail rejects?

Tags: phishing, spam, outlook

At my work email, which is handled by MS Office 365 Outlook, I keep getting phishing emails, typically 3 times a week, usually with some attachment "your company's monthly financial report" or "voicemail recording - high priority", or "proforma invoice". All of that is obvious BS, because none of that applies to me.

Those attachments are nearly always thinly disguised html files that would (presumably) forward me to an imitation log-in web page, or present a log-in via some script. Sometimes the phishing email even tries to legitimize the fake login script, saying "a login will be required to see the attachment".

A few times I uploaded the suspected phishing attachment to VirusTotal, and it's always reliably detected as a phishing or malicious attachment.

I can't fathom why Microsoft 365 isn't capable of detecting and blocking these easy-to-identify phishing emails.

Just for kicks, I tried forwarding one such email to my personal Gmail account, but Gmail smartly and immediately declined to deliver it, replying "Remote Server returned '552-5.7.0 This message was blocked because its content presents a potential 552-5.7.0 security issue."

I religiously keep clicking the "report phishing" in Outlook, but these emails keep coming.

If there's anything I can do to improve this situation, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Your work M365 administrator may have adjusted the sensitivity of the junk mail settings. You need to work with them to see how to improve the sensitivity.